# Escaping ruby string

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have a string with two single quotes. i.e "lady's lady's"

I want to escape the quotes so I get: "lady\'s lady\'s".

I have tried the following:

```
> "lady's lady's".gsub("'", "\\'")
 => "ladys lady'ss ladyss" 

> "lady's lady's".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
 => "lady\\'s lady\\'s" 

> "lady's lady's".gsub("'", "\'")
 => "lady's lady's"
```

Any help?

Comment: `"\'"` is equal to `"'"`, so I feel that `"lady\\'s lady\\'s"` may be what you want. But `irb` or `pry` prints it in escaped way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"lady's lady's".gsub("'", "\\\\'") # => "lady\\'s lady\\'s"
```

As @Neil mentioned see below :

```
"lady's lady's".gsub(/'/, "\\\\\'").chars.to_a 
# => ["l",
#     "a",
#     "d",
#     "y",
#     "\\",
#     "'",
#     "s",
#     " ",
#     "l",
#     "a",
#     "d",
#     "y",
#     "\\",
#     "'",
#     "s"]
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. It has double "\"

Comment: I am looking for: "lady\'s lady\'s".

Comment: @Tony: `"lady's lady's".gsub(/'/, "\\\\'").chars.to_a` shows that the displayed double ` \\ ` is just an artefact in irb. It's the correct answer I think!

Comment: @NeilSlater: No. The string `"\\\\"` is two backslashes. Try `puts "\\\\".length`. In fact `"\\\\\'"` is two backslashes followed by an unnecessarily-escaped apostrophe.

Comment: @Borodin: Try `"'".gsub("'","\\\\'").length` :-)

Comment: Both are *2* I can see `"'".gsub("'","\\\\'").length # => 2
"\\\\".length # => 2`.

Comment: This is because using a literal replacement string of `\'` replaces each apostrophe with the value of the global variable `$'` - the string after the match. So the first `'` is replaced with `s lady's` and second with `s`, resulting in the bizarre `ladys lady'ss ladyss`. You have to use a literal string of `\\'` to get the effect you want. It's much neater to use a look-ahead and avoid having to replace the apostrophe: `puts "lady's lady's".gsub(/(?=')/, '\\')`.

Answer (score 5):

Classically, the characters that need to be escaped are the non-alphanumerics. Perl's [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), for instance, escape everything that isn't a number, a letter, or an underscore.

You can replicate this behaviour by using `gsub`:

```
str = "lady's lady's"

puts str.gsub(/(?=\W)/, '\\')
```

**output**

```
lady\'s\ lady\'s
```

If you particularly don't want anything but the apostrophes escaping then the regex is simple to change, replacing `(?=\W)` with `(?=')`.

---

**Note**

The result

```
> "lady's lady's".gsub("'", "\\'")
 => "ladys lady'ss ladyss"
```

is because using a literal replacement string of `«\'»` replaces each apostrophe with the value of the global variable `$'` - the string after the match.

So the first apostrophe is replaced with `«s lady's»` and the second with `«s»`, resulting in the bizarre `«ladys lady'ss ladyss»`.

You have to use a literal replacement string of `«\\'»` to replace with just `«\'»`

It's much neater to use a look-ahead and avoid having to replace the apostrophe:

```
> puts "lady's lady's".gsub(/(?=')/, '\\')
lady\'s lady\'s
=> nil
```

Comment: I do think this regex is easier on the eye. Also, your explanation of the "ladys lady'ss ladyss" result is worth adding to this answer IMO.

Comment: @NeilSlater Should I delete my post ?

Comment: @NeilSlater: Good call. Done.

Comment: @Priti: No I don't think so. I often appreciate seeing multiple answers to interesting SO questions. Besides which, it is the accepted answer.